# Sending a token in a Post Request using python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to make a post request in python. I have tested the request in postman and it works, but when I try to run it in in a python 3.6 script, I am getting a `403 invalid token` error. Is there something I am missing?

The current code that postman is giving me is as follows

```
import requests

url = "https://www.deviantart.com/dapi/v1/browse/thumbs"

querystring = {"iid":"598m980bb6e26e5be0a33d4a88ed1c570026-jshtsqc2-1.21","mp":"5"}

payload = ""
headers = {
    'origin': "https://www.deviantart.com",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'accept': "*/*",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "cd95e1a8-2203-eaaf-91ee-4cf56ee41875"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

This request works on my browser and in the postman app but not in python

Comment: why is there a 'postman-token' header?  What does the request itself have to do with postman? - should that header possibly have a different key name? - I know basically what Postman is, but am curious of the statement "The current code that postman is giving me is as follows".  So Postman can produce Python code?

Comment: That is a good question? I wondered that too.

I used intereceptor to capture the post request that the browser made and then I copied the code into a python script.

Postman is able to make the post request successfully and i am assuming it is attempting to output all of the information it used as python code but it could be different.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for the clarification.  I don't know anything about this particular API, either oauth or the deviantart api.  From where is the API expecting to get the token?  I assume it wouldn't be looking in a header field named 'postman-token'.  But I don't see it elsewhere in the request, unless iid is the token that the endpoint is complaining about.  One thing I've noticed that is bad API design is that any request at all produces "403 invalid token".  It seems like it should produce something like "403 token not supplied" if the token was supplied in the wrong place or not at all.

Comment: Why not use [DeviantArt](https://github.com/neighbordog/deviantart)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I figured out something. I use the RSS API I can send query requests that way. So hey. If it works it works.